# JQuery Mobile - Space between content and footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing my first mobile website with JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 which only have to work on the iPad with apple-mobile-web-app-capable.

Everything I want to achieve is to delete the white space between the content div and footer div. I have no clue where it comes from and how to get rid of it.

```
    <div data-role="page" id="pagec" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-id="head2" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <?php getNav(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<div data-role="content">
  <!-- SWIPE -->
  <?php getContent(); ?>  
  <!-- //SWIPE -->    
</div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <?php getForm(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The space only appears on the iPad - no problems with Firefox.

There are similar topics to this but no solution worked for me...

Comment: Your css would help us identify the problem. One other question, are you using safari or google chrome?

Comment: can you provide an online demo (like jsfiddle), where we can access it with our ipads?

Comment: I didn't make any adaptations to the JQuery Mobile CSS.

Comment: Then a jsfiddle like 23tux stated would help the most.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Stressfish/8P8yv/

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? reset height of _content_ div if that div doesn't fill the screen? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eaRke/

Answer (score 0):

If your page only has to work on iPad, then maybe you could just use CSS? The following should have the effect of making the footer overlap on the content in Firefox, but it should solve the problem on the iPad

enter the following in the header of the page:

```
<style>
     #footer {
     position:relative;
     top:-20px; }
     </style>
```

change the footer div to give it an id

```
 <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
   <?php getForm(); ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My fault! The height-attribute in the viewport-meta was wrong.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

...changed to...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```